# Do the judges really receive menu at the beginning of the elimination challenge?

Tags: reality-tv, the-taste

In *The Taste* (at least in the [British version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taste_(UK_TV_series))), when the contestants start cooking for the elimination challenge, the judges receive the menu with the dishes that are going to be served. This means that the contestants cannot change their chosen dish or any of its main ingredients throughout the challenge, which is in contrast to other cooking contest TV shows that I've seen.

Is this really the case or is it only presented this way to the viewers?

Comment: I wouldn't know, but note that declaring the ingredients before starting adds an element of difficulty..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Understood, still this approach is really unusual in this kind of shows, simply because their contestants often change their original concept, either because they are forced to (because something goes wrong, sometimes it's even impossible to continue with the original dish) or they simply change their mind.

Comment: LOL! You just reminded me of a cooking show on which a chap was going to cook a pork chop. The judges had ..skeptical looks on their faces as if to say *"This is going to have to be the best damn pork chop ever cooked, to win here!"*. The look on the guy's face when he realized he'd ***burnt the chop*** was ..bloody hilarious! He might've be able to change details, but that was too much. He knew he'd utterly failed.

Comment: Don't most cooking shows dictate the main ingredients?  I know master chef does.

Comment: @cde Not really, even in _MasterChef_ it's not always the case and even if it is, you can always change the dish, if it's still possible and the dish hasn't been dictated.